# Sound sometimes disappears, definitely when skype is installed

Tags: 12.04, sound, skype

After I upgraded to Xubuntu 12.04 from 11.10, I noticed skype was uninstalled, so I reinstalled it with aptitude. Now if I install skype I don't have sound any more in my mp4 clips.

If I uninstall skype I have sound again in my mp4 clips, unless I pause the clip and resume, then the sound is gone again.

I tested this on parole and vlc. Is there a fix or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing `VLC`>`extra`>`preferences`>`audio`: choose `alsa audio-output` along with `use S/PDIF if possible` checked.